# Emergency mode on Fedora 21 - mcelog

Tags: fedora, mcelog

My Fedora 21 system boots directly into the emergency mode. 
There is the error message: `unable to init device /dev/mcelog (rc -5)`

It says try: `systemctl default` to boot to default mode; this works. Then the machine reboots nicely. With the next reboot -- the same again.

Maybe it is necessary to know that I also have input/output errors.
If I type ^D in emergency mode, the boot continues nicely, but, for example, `yum update` does not work because of input / output errors.

I am Using Fedora 3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64) 21.

The error message also says: type `journalctl -xb`; this is the output: [journalctl xb](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10262231/journalctl-xb.txt.html)

First lines:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2015-01-08 09:06:21 CET, end at Fri 2015-02-06 13:08:34 CET. --
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[120]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 141.7M, trying to leave 212.6M free of 1.3G available → current limit 141.7M).
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[120]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 141.7M, trying to leave 212.6M free of 1.3G available → current limit 141.7M).
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Linux version 3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 03:08:44 UTC 2014
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Disabled fast string operations
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009f7ff] usable
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000dc000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000b4eeffff] usable
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b4ef0000-0x00000000b4efefff] ACPI data
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b4eff000-0x00000000b4efffff] ACPI NVS
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b4f00000-0x00000000b4ffffff] usable
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec0ffff] reserved
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffe0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
```

(I'd think important) middle Lines:

```
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 10
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: mip6: Mobile IPv6
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 17
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: mce: Unable to init device /dev/mcelog (rc: -5)
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Fedora kernel signing key: a3deaae72f85c63029d7879041c633438a40e688'
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel: registered taskstats version 1
Feb 06 13:03:26 localhost.localdomain kernel:   Magic number: 3:210:76
```

Last Lines:

```
    Feb 06 13:03:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
Feb 06 13:03:31 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Feb 06 13:03:31 localhost.localdomain lvm[487]: /dev/sr0: open failed: No medium found
Feb 06 13:03:31 localhost.localdomain lvm[487]: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora" monitored
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root: Duplicate or bad block in use!
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root: Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 1316688: 5439532
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root: Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 1328717: 5439532
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root: (There are 2 inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks.)
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root: File /var/log/wtmp (inode #1316688, mod time Fri Feb  6 13:03:20 2015)
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root:         /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log (inode #1328717, mod time Fri Feb  6 13:01:52 2015)
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root:
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: fsck failed with error code 4.
Feb 06 13:03:32 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[489]: Running request emergency.target/start/replace
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain alsactl[505]: alsactl 1.0.28 daemon started
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain alsactl[505]: /usr/sbin/alsactl: load_state:1729No soundcards found...
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[485]: Permanent journal is using 96.0M (max allowed 4.0G, trying to leave 4.0G free of 35.1G available → current limit 4.0G).
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[485]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 537.241ms for 1381 entries.
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled!
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: vmw_vmci 0000:00:07.7: Found VMCI PCI device at 0x11080, irq 16
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: vmw_vmci 0000:00:07.7: Using capabilities 0xc
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: vmw_vmci 0000:00:07.7: irq 56 for MSI/MSI-X
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: vmw_vmci 0000:00:07.7: irq 57 for MSI/MSI-X
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: Guest personality initialized and is active
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: VMCI host device registered (name=vmci, major=10, minor=59)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initialized host personality
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: parport_pc 00:05: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[553]: checking bus 2, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-1"
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[553]: bus: 2, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Feb 06 13:03:33 localhost.localdomain systemd-udevd[526]: starting version 217
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: Adding 3014652k swap on /dev/mapper/fedora-swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3014652k FS
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain lvm[573]: 3 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora" now active
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[575]: /dev/sda1: clean, 419/128016 files, 129336/512000 blocks
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev sda1, type ext4), uses xattr
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home: Duplicate or bad block in use!
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home: Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 2359436: 9445606
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home: Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 2359723: 9445606
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home: (There are 2 inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks.)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home: File /dder/.cache/mozilla/firefox/fl6tebaj.default/cache2/entries (inode #2359436, mod time Fri Feb  6 12:58:01 2015)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home:         /dder/.mozilla/firefox/fl6tebaj.default/prefs.js (inode #2359723, mod time Sun Jan 11 21:22:16 2015)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home:
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: /dev/mapper/fedora-home: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: fsck failed with error code 4.
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain systemd-fsck[589]: Running request emergency.target/start/replace
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Feb 06 13:03:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev dm-2, type ext4), uses xattr
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain systemd-tmpfiles[608]: remove(/var/lib/rpm/__db.001): Input/output error
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1441: inode #1316485: comm systemd-tmpfile: deleted inode referenced: 1328892
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain auditd[612]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 618
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain audispd[618]: priority_boost_parser called with: 4
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain audispd[618]: max_restarts_parser called with: 10
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain audispd[618]: audispd initialized with q_depth=150 and 1 active plugins
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain auditd[612]: Init complete, auditd 2.4.1 listening for events (startup state enable)
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1305 audit(1423224215.337:4): audit_pid=612 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
Feb 06 13:03:35 localhost.localdomain auditctl[613]: No rules
Feb 06 13:04:08 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757: group 161, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 12 vs 13 free clusters
Feb 06 13:08:30 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): error count since last fsck: 230
Feb 06 13:08:30 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): initial error at time 1421083217: ext4_lookup:1441: inode 1722417
Feb 06 13:08:30 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): last error at time 1423224248: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757
Feb 06 13:08:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): error count since last fsck: 36
Feb 06 13:08:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): initial error at time 1421083213: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757
Feb 06 13:08:34 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): last error at time 1423223563: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:757
```

I've tried to boot from Live-USB and typed `fdisk -l`. This is a part of the output from `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x337f0bd9

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1026047   1024000   500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1026048 234440703 233414656 111.3G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 2.9 GiB, 3087007744 bytes, 6029312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 58.4 GiB, 62662901760 bytes, 122388480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.7 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa1d41386

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     8064 30719999 30711936 14.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

`sda` is my Fedora system, `sdb` is my encrypted Windows, all running with a separate bootloader.

The output of `e2fsck` brings:

```
e2fsck /dev/sda
e2fsck 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
/dev/sda is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

e2fsck /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

e2fsck /dev/sda2
e2fsck 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
/dev/sda2 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

When booting from Live-USB `e2fsck /dev/sda1` yields `clean drive`, and `e2fsck /dev/sda2` brings `/dev/sda2 is in use. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`

Comment: can't you simply paste first line of text ? following your link bring a .exe.

Comment: Have you tried running `e2fsck` on whatever `dm-0` and `dm-2` are? `dm-2` is probably `/dev/mapper/fedora-home`. That's the actual error up above. The mcelog message is probably just because the system doesn't boot far enough to create that device.

Comment: Referring to the ext4 filesystem error at Feb 06 13:03:34

Comment: I edited the post with outputs of `e2fsck`. However, booting from Live-USB leads to the message, that the drive seems to be in use. How can I aviod this, to output more from `e2fck`

Comment: Note that Fedora 21 is end of life. Upgrade, or move to e.g. CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

Live-USB apparently mounts your filesystems automatically. To repair them you will have to unmount them before using e2fsck. And since you have LVM, your file systems will be listed as linked files in the directory /dev/mapper, so don't try to umount or use e2fsck on /dev/sda2 for example but rather on /dev/mapper/whatever (like /dev/mapper/vg_hostname_lv_root, /dev/mapper/vg_hostname_lv_home) ... since that is where your filesystems are built when you use LVM.